# Trouble loading XML document from project

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML document in my project that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<event>
  <name>Test Event</name>
  <date>06/19/1967</date>
  <description>Birthday</description>
  <blogURL></blogURL>
</event>
```

I want to create a webpage that accepts user input and replaces these values.

Here is my aspx page

```
<asp:Panel ID="NewEvent" CssClass="eventSection" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="MessageBox" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="NewEventName" placeholder="Event Name" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="NewDate" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="NewDescription" runat="server" placeholder="Description of event" TextMode="MultiLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="NewURL" runat="server" placeholder="Leave blank if none"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadButton ID="EditXML" runat="server" Text="Submit Event" OnClick="EditXML_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

My code behind to grab these values

```
    string newEventName = NewEventName.Text;
    string newEventDescription = NewDescription.Text;
    string newEventDate = NewDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToString();
    string newEventURL = NewURL.Text;
```

And finally, actually inserting values into xml document

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("/PressSection.xml");
    doc.Element("name").Value = newEventName;
    doc.Element("date").Value = newEventDate;
    doc.Element("description").Value = newEventDescription;
    doc.Element("blogURL").Value = newEventURL;
    doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));
```

The XML file is located in the same directory as my aspx file

[image]

What I have tried

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("PressSection.xml");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

which gives this error

[image: error]

Which I'm not sure why. When I set a break point and hover over my values, they are filled.

I've also tried

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));
```

Which gives me the same error as above.

Finally, I've also tried

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("\\PressSection.xml");
```

Which gives me this error

[image: final image]

I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: NRE is likely usual duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it... You may want to start with solving that error.

Comment: Unless you are re-throwing an exception that occured elsewhere, the `exception` you are getting is very clear, `NewEventName` must be `null` when you try to call `.Text` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the first child element of the current container (element / document) *only*.  So each of your queries like this one:

```
doc.Element("name").Value = newEventName;
```

Will return null, and your subsequent access of `Value` will result in a null reference exception.  You should get the `event` element first:

```
var event = doc.Element("event");
event.Element("name").Value = newEventName;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I understand now.